# How do i release memory when using replaceScene

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, cocos2d-iphone

First. Thx for your help and sorry about my poor english...

I use cocos2d to develope 2d game.

In game, i use 4 scene (main, rank, setting, game)

In Appdelegate, i make mainscene with code bellow.

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene: [MainMenuLayer scene]];
```

And i use "replaceScene" to change between scenes with code bellow.
(in MainmenyLayer)

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1.0 scene:[TutorialLayer scene]]];
```

(in TutorialLayer)

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1.0 scene:[GameLayer scene]]];
```

it seems work well.

but when i testing memory leak. i found there is leak between scene change.

i guess everytime scene changed. new object of scene created and didn't release.

i checked dealloc function and it is working. like bellow-

```
-(void) dealloc {
    [self release]
    [super dealloc];
}
```

but when i run leak profile, i saw memory constantly stacked everytime i change between scenes.

how i managed memory release like this situation?

once again, Thx for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to release the CCLayer with [self release] in the dealloc method, cocos2d takes care of that for you. 
In fact all Cocos2D nodes are autorelease objects and are released by cocos2d automatically.
Only if you are allocating anything yourself using alloc, retain or new do you have to release it.

Comment: thank you for answer!. so if i have memory leak that isn't related to replaceScene at all?